# Write loops and arrays in assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to learn arrays and loops in asm. Can anybody convert these or help?

```
for (int a = 0; a < amount; a++)
    templetter =  originalletter[a];    
Enletters [i] = templetter;
```

Comment: Assembly language for which processor?

Comment: Which syntax? Intel or AT & T?

Answer (score 0):

At the lowest level, a loop *(assuming it doesn't get optimized away)* will typically look like this:

```
LoopStart:
Set loopVariable = 0
  Do loopy-stuff
Compare loopVariable with maxValue
If loopVariable < maxValue, goto LoopStart
```

---

As you learn in C-class, the following two expressions are the same

```
myArray[i]
*(myArray + i)
```

That second statement is exactly how the array access will be translated by the compiler:

```
Add i† to myArray (the memory address of the first array-element)
The result is the memory address of the i-th element
```

<sup>†</sup> *Note that you will need to multiply i by the size of an array element eg. a `struct` with 2 `int`s will be 2-words large*